# trying to run test java from cmd

Tags: java, testing, cmd

I am trying to run my Java program from the command prompt.
When I do the main method inside my class it works just fine when I use the following command :

```
path\out\production> java -cp .;"../../../lib/*" Class Package.ClassName
```

But when I try to run the class test with the same command but changing out to test like this:

```
path\out\test> java -cp .;"../../../lib/*" Class Package.Class Name
```

It gives me an error.

I don't really know what I am missing.

Comment: which error is it showing?

Comment: Is Package.ClassName vs Package.Class Name a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You went up and down to the `test` directory. Your main class is in `production`. It worked because you added the current directory to your classpath, but now that you changed the current directory you need to run it as follows:

```
java -cp ../production;"../../../lib/" Class Package.ClassName
```

I added ../production to the path to "emulate" the missing current directory: note that it works in `production` too and in all subdirectories of `out`

Note that if your Java program is accessing some files in a relative way, it won't work since you changed the current directory.

Comment: I just run it but still is not working showing the error : Could not find or load main class ..but I have the main class and know is not working from production either

Comment: did you type `Class Name` or `ClassName` as @Bookeater suggested? My answer has the added space typo. If you copied that, no wonder it fails.